# Can't call method "import" without a package or object reference

Tags: perl, cgi

My Perl CGI program uses the `import` function, I am calling a `.pm` file.

In the following code, when `$projectID` is a string—for example `"try"`—there are no import errors. But if it is numeric—e.g. `"0689"`—then the following error appears

> Can't call method "import" without a package or object reference at aa.cgi line 993.

```
my $projectID    = "0689"
my $gTable       = "vg" . $tm . ".pm";
my $new_vPath    = $hconfig::usersPNG . $vnm;
my $gen_listPath = $usersTMP . $gTable;

if ( -e $new_venPath && -e $gen_listPath ) {

    require $projectID . '/' . $gTable;
    import $projectID . '/' . $gTable;  # try2/vg77.pm -> no error # 0689/vg76.pm -> import error

    ...
}
```

Comment: What do you think this code is supposed to do? You usually don't use filenames with this, but package names. The idea is that the file name and the package name map to each other, and then Perl knows what to do.

Comment: There is no `import` function; it is a *method* defined by modules that wish to export their values to external code, and requires a *package name* as part of the method call. What is in `$projectID.'/'.$gTable`? Is it a proper module definition? It isn't advisable to learn a language by making wild guesses at the correct syntax. Please read the documentation before asking for free world-wide help with nonsensical code.

Comment: sorry for not being clear with my question. $projectID.'/'.$gTable is my perl module filename. And this perl module is a package that contains hashes. So my idea is after importing the perl module, i wanted to extract the values from it. Here the problem is with filename if it starts with a string, i dont see any import errors but if its numeric then import error.

Comment: @Mikhail: Your edit has made the question *substantially worse*. In particular, replacing ***e.g.*** with ***i.e.*** is *wrong*. Please don't make corrections if you don't know the language very well.

Comment: Please [edit] your question and include an example of one of your packages. What's in them? You ought to use the package name, not the file name.

Comment: @Borodin Thanks for the review. I'll take this into account.

Answer (score 3):

What is going on here is that [`import`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/import.html) is *not* a built-in Perl function. Instead, it is a [method](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlobj.html#A-Method-is-Simply-a-Subroutine) that [`use`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/use.html) typically calls on a *package* after it is loaded - you seem to be trying to call it on a *filename*, which won't work.

I guess you are trying to dynamically load a package based on the contents of those variables. Here's one way of several to do that:

```
my $filename = '/path/to/Package/Name.pm';
my $packagename = 'Package::Name';
require $filename;
$packagename->import();
```

One thing to keep in mind about loading modules dynamically like this is that, unlike modules loaded by `use`, Perl won't know about the functions exported from those packages at compile time. The consequence is that you can't omit parentheses from calls to those functions.

So for example: If you have a module `Foo` that exports a function `foo`, you could say: `use Foo; foo "bar";`. But if you instead load `Foo` with the above code, you have to say `foo("bar");`.

By the way, I doubt that `0689::vg76` is the name of one of your packages. If you could explain more about what you're trying to load, i.e. what the files `0689/vg76.pm` look like and what you're loading from them (like, do they actually have a `sub import`?), perhaps we could suggest a more fitting method of loading them.

---

The reason that `import $projectID . '/' . $gTable;` is still valid syntax is that Perl is interpreting it as [Indirect Object Syntax](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlobj.html#Indirect-Object-Syntax), wherein `method_name $object @parameters;` is taken as `$object->method_name(@parameters);`.

The indirect object syntax is mostly used when `print`ing to a filehandle, as in `print $filehandle $output`, but other than that, its use is **discouraged**, one reason being the confusing syntax issues you are observing here.

You can use use [`B::Deparse`](http://perldoc.perl.org/B/Deparse.html) to see how Perl interprets your source code:

```
$ perl -MO=Deparse,-p -e 'import $projectID . "/" . $gTable;'
(($projectID->import . '/') . $gTable);
```

The reason you are getting that error message is that, on Perl releases before v5.18 (references: [bug](https://rt.perl.org/Public/Bug/Display.html?id=105922), [commit](https://perl5.git.perl.org/perl.git/commit/7156e69ab), [delta](http://perldoc.perl.org/perl5180delta.html#Selected-Bug-Fixes)), the string on the left of the `->` was required to be a known name, or start with an alphanumeric character. (And even though as of v5.18, you can theoretically say `"0689/vg76"->import`, that's almost certainly not what you want, as I explained above.)

Comment: @ikegami I was quoting [the doc](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/import.html). If you could clarify what the distinction is, I can edit my answer.